# RxJS concat method signature

Tags: rxjs

In `concat.d.ts` files we can find following definitions of `concat` operator:

```
export declare function concat<T>(this: Observable<T>, scheduler?: IScheduler): Observable<T>;
export declare function concat<T, T2>(this: Observable<T>, v2: ObservableInput<T2>, scheduler?: IScheduler): Observable<T | T2>;
export declare function concat<T, T2, T3>(this: Observable<T>, v2: ObservableInput<T2>, v3: ObservableInput<T3>, scheduler?: IScheduler): Observable<T | T2 | T3>;
/* List goes on with more and mode T4, T5 ... */
```

All signatures with mote than one generic type (i.e. starting from `<T1, T2>`) are clear (at least i hope so):

- After `this` observable of type `T1` will complete, start second observable for signature `T2`:  `Observable.from([1,2,3]).concat(Observable.of('HI'))`
- After `this` observable of type `T1` will complete, start second observable for signature `T2`, after it start third one with type `T3`:    `Observable.from([1,2,3]).concat(Observable.of('HI'), Observable.of('Hi there'))`
- And so on...

But how to translate the first one? How can `concat` works with no further observables passed into it?:
`Observable.from([1,2,3]).concat()`

Comment: `Observable.from([1,2,3]).concat()` is equivalent to `Observable.concat(Observable.from([1,2,3]))`. Somewhat pointless, but valid.

Comment: But does such construct let me processing further the stream after some portition will complete? I.e. `Observable.from([1,2,3]).concat().map(r => 5)` ?

Comment: Yes, the result will just be the source with nothing concatenated.

Comment: Hey, can you please post your commentary as answer to this question? I'd be happy to accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the introduction of pipeable operators in RxJS v5.5, the patched `concat` method - `Observable.prototype.concat` - was a convenience method that was [implemented using the static `concat` factory function](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.4.3/src/operator/concat.ts#L67-L69).

That is, this:

```
Observable.from([1,2,3]).concat(Observable.from[4, 5]))
```

was equivalent to this:

```
Observable.concat(
  Observable.from([1,2,3]),
  Observable.from[4, 5])
)
```

It's possible to call `Observable.concat` and pass a single argument, like this:

```
Observable.concat(
  Observable.from([1,2,3])
)
```

Which is equivalent to this:

```
Observable.from([1,2,3]).concat()
```

So, when the patched `concat` method is called as above, nothing is concatenated. It's valid, but somewhat pointless, as the `concat` just re-emits the notifications from the source observable.